# What is the key code to hide the keyboard button?

Tags: android, hide, keycode

In my app, I need to find the keyboard hide operation when I press the below button. For that, I need to find the key code of that button, however, I don't know the key code of the button. Can anyone tell me what the keycode of this button is?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        hide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

This is code that worked for the back button, but not the hide keyboard button.

Comment: you want the keycode of back button ?

Comment: My problem is when i pressed back my key board is hide and also in the same time i need to perform one operation. So where can i write the code. But here the code is working when i pressed second time.